# pass variable to document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript

Hello i have a function and i need to pass a variable to `document.getElementById();`

my function is like this

```
        function showComment(theField) {
            var x = document.getElementById("theField");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.setAttribute('style', 'display: block !important');
            } else {
                x.setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important');
            }
        }
```

and my html button like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn-reset" onclick="showComment(theDiv)"> Show/hide </button>
```

Comment: So why do you pass a string literal instead of your variable?

Comment: Btw, don't use `!important`, and don't use `setAttribute` when you can just assign to `x.style.display`.

Comment: Don’t modify style from JavaScript. Apply classes instead. And try to not use getelementbyid but use bindings instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost correct. Use:

```
var x = document.getElementById(theField); // (no quotes)
```

Quotes indicate a *literal value*. If you don't use quotes, you use the variable.

And in the HTML, you *do* want quotes to pass a string value:

```
... onclick="showComment('theDiv')" ...
```

What this should do now is select the element with id `#theDiv`.

Comment: hey man you re a life saver the best!! Thanks so much. Good luck man!!!!

Comment: @andrew06041990 I'm glad I helped! Make sure to mark this answer as accepted to show posterity it helped you!

Comment: It may help to know that the error here is `Uncaught ReferenceError: theDiv is not defined` which gives some additional context to Jonathan's answer above. "theDiv" is attempting to be passed currently as a reference to a variable (that doesn't exist), not the string literal you are intending.

Comment: Inline event handlers are essentially `eval` inside HTML markup - they're bad practice and result in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener